# .getElementById(" ") not working as required

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the text inside a header (h1) depending on the time. The value does not change. Not sure why it is not working - tried multiple changes and solutions thus far.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  <img src = "image.png" width = "25%" height = "auto"/>
    <h1 id = "ce" style="font-weight: normal; font-family: 'lato', sans-serif; font-size:80px;">No Event</h1>
</center>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="100%" height="500"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
frameborder="0"/>
  <script>
 function headerChange(){
 var d = new Date();
 var m = d.getMinutes();
 var h = d.getHours();
 if(h == 7 && m>=45){
    document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event1";
  }
  if(h == 8 && m>=00){
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event2";
  }
  if(h == 8 && m>=15){
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event3";
  }
  if(h == 8 && m>=45){
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event4";
  }
  if(h == 9 && m>=00){
   document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event5";
  }
  if(h == 9 && m>=15){
     document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event6";
   }
   }
  headerChange();
  setTimeout(headerChange, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` runs your function only once, use `setInterval` instead, or add another `setTimeout` in `headerChange`.

Comment: Ok, but you see, it's not changing even once..

Comment: you miss the closing `}` of function headerChange

Comment: The code changes the header only between 7:45 am and 9:59 am ... Have you tested at a correct time? Also, you should put the script either into `head` or into `body`, currently the HTML is invalid.

Comment: Yes. I have tried the correct time.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? usually IDE find codes typo. also you can use jshint

Comment: I've pasted the code at https://jsfiddle.net/mf1f2f22/ (with hardcoded h and m).  For some reason, it works there, but only if the iframe is removed.

Comment: Thank you! That worked @racraman. It was the iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answer! @racraman figured out the problem. It was the youtube iFrame. Once I removed that particular demo iFrame my code began to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please close the headerChange function . I think its missing the closing bracket.
Secondly , you are using both setTimeout and recursive calling . I would suggest that don't call it recursively and you could do like this

```
function headerChange(){
 var d = new Date();
 var m = d.getMinutes();
 var h = d.getHours();
 if(h == 7 && m>=45){
    document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event1";
  }
  if(h == 8 && m>=00){
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event2";
  }
  if(h == 8 && m>=15){
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event3";
  }
  if(h == 8 && m>=45){
  document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event4";
  }
  if(h == 9 && m>=00){
   document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event5";
  }
  if(h == 9 && m>=15){
     document.getElementById("ce").innerHTML = "event6";
   }
}
  setTimeout(headerChange, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(headerChange, 1000);

function headerChange(){
 var d = new Date();
 var m = d.getMinutes();
 var h = d.getHours();
 var elem = document.getElementById("ce");

  if(h == 7 && m>=45){
     elem.innerHTML = "event1";
  }else if(h == 8 && m>=00){
     elem.innerHTML = "event2";
  }else if(h == 8 && m>=15){
     elem.innerHTML = "event3";
  }else if(h == 8 && m>=45){
     elem.innerHTML = "event4";
  }else if(h == 9 && m>=00){
     elem.innerHTML = "event5";
  }else if(h == 9 && m>=15){
     elem.innerHTML = "event6";
  }
}
</script>
```